# Escape sequence for Keyboard Down Arrow

Tags: java, android, bluetooth, hid

I have an Android JAVA app that connects to a USB Bluetooth keyboard emulator that I bought from here http://intelletto.com/products

So far I'm able to send **Escape sequences** like `\t`, `\n` but I'm not sure how to send a command for the Key Down event. Here's how I'm doing it:

```
char str = '\t';
byte[] command = String.valueOf(str).getBytes();
mBTService.write(command);
```

Also, I got this HID ASCII Mapping table from the USB provider which I'm not sure how to use it.

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1hZV5mdaPCN93BK6bYZeX2h9y5lx3R2hS/view?usp=sharing

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/keylistener.html - I am not sure if that can be adapted - or native web app events.. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/keydown_event. My exposure to mobile apps - came via Ionic - where you hooked into native webAPI stuff - via Angular. Haven't done native Java for Android.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According with the map chart you posted, it must be surely like this:

```
byte[] command = new byte[]{(byte)201};
mBTService.write(command);
```

... as `201` is the code for "DownArr" (in this specific mapping, altough that is not a standard codification).